# Fill Not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js

So I am making a game using p5.js. With this game I have made an obstacle that will fall from the top of the canvas. I have applied the `fill` tool to color my obstacles. I have also used this for the player. Before I had made my obstacle object, there was no error, but I receive and error saying

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fill is not defined
    at new obstacle (script.js:22)
    at script.js:27
```

```
function obstacle() {
    this.x = xPositions;
    this.y = yPositions;
    this.diameter = 15;
    fill(209, 144, 4);
    this.display2 = function() {
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.diameter, this.diameter);
    };
}    
var asteroid = new obstacle();
asteroid.display2();
```

Comment: we cant see fill to. Where is fill?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] instead of a disconnected snippet of code? Better yet post a CodePen or JSFiddle.

Comment: you'll need to define the function `fill`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that this line is outside of any functions:

```
var asteroid = new obstacle();
```

Which means that this is happening **before** the `setup()` function is called. This is a no-no. Read here for more info: [Why can't I assign variables using p5 functions and variables before setup()?](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-cant-i-assign-variables-using-p5-functions-and-variables-before-setup)

Basically, you can't use P5.js functions until after `setup()` is called, because the P5.js library hasn't been loaded yet.

In other words, move the initialization to be inside the `setup()` function. Note that the declaration can still be outside, like this:

```
var asteroid;
function setup(){
  asteroid = new Obstacle();
}
```

But taking a step back, it doesn't really make sense to call the `fill()` function inside the constructor anyway, because nothing should be painted when you first instantiate the object. You probably want to move it to be inside the `display()` function inside your `Obstacle` object.

If you still can't get it working, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question post and we'll go from there. Good luck.